# MYSQL number of records inserted and updated

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below SQL statment

```
INSERT INTO my_counts (type,code,count) SELECT type,id ,1 from my_data WHERE user_id=10
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1;
```

Here **type,code** is a composite primary key .

Could you please let me know how can I find out the number of records inserted and also the number of records updated separately  ?

I know **SELECT ROW_COUNT()** gives the effected rows ( 2 for update and 1 for insert) .
But how to find out separately

```
1) the number of rows updated 
2) the number of rows inserted
```

Thanks for your help

Regards

Kiran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a good way to get this from the diagnostics information.

In any case, supposing that you've controlled it so that only the rows *just* `INSERT` ed are in the table (or will only be queried), this can be simply retrieved after the fact:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Inserted, SUM(count - 1) as Updated
FROM my_counts;
```

(please note that, as included in my SQLFiddle [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20b13/1/0), these numbers can actually be predicted from the base data).

Comment: nice solution , but if there is already data in counts table ? :) Kiran

Comment: @Bujji - Then you can either predict it (like the last query in my example), or you're going to need some discriminating column (like some sort of insert batch id, a timestamp, etc).