# Number of lines updated

Tags: mysql, sql

Good morning,

Is it possible to get the number of rows modified by an update in MySQL using a MySQL command?

I found this post but I didn't understand

[MYSQL number of records inserted and updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942024/mysql-number-of-records-inserted-and-updated?rq=1)

Thanks.

Comment: @Ben, your linked question is about procedures, this one iis more general.

Comment: It's about an update statement, `ROW_COUNT()` will work inside and outside a procedure @Tomas and this is therefore the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ROW_COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) function in MySQL:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = 'data' WHERE `id` <= 10;
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

This will output the number of changed/deleted/added rows for `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `INSERT`.

If you wish to know how many rows the previous `SELECT` query returned, use the [`FOUND_ROWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) function:

```
SELECT `column` FROM `table` WHERE `id` <= 10;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/update.html

mysql update command return the number of modified rows...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL UPDATE returns number of rows modified by it self, you don't need to call any extra commands

Please refer to documentation: [13.2.10. UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

> UPDATE returns the number of rows that were actually changed. The mysql_info() C API 
>   function returns the number of rows that were matched and updated and the number of 
>   warnings that occurred during the UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by

update tablename set Name = 'Dinner'
select @@ROWCOUNT -- gives  number of rows affcted

Comment: That looks like T-SQL, not MySQL.